# Does lack of zone control delay hurt heat pump?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heat-pump

I had a new HVAC single heat-pump system installed with dual zone controls: 
2 thermostats and 2 dampers for separate zones.

The system works, but the zone control board does not have any time delay between one zone turning off and the other zone calling for heat/AC. Normally, a thermostat enforces a 5 minute time delay before restarting after power is removed.

Will the short off-time damage the compressor over time even though it doesn't trip the overload?

Answer (score 3):

Some newer compressors have a built-in delay to protect them from damage.  You should check the number of recommended cycles per hour in the manual to find out if this is an issue for your unit.

Damage could be caused by overheating over time, or a [flooded start](http://www.fridgetech.com/articles/recipfailmodes/#GlossB) - depending on the design of the unit.